# Disbale New tab opening which clicked ctrl+click inside iframe url

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

How to disable ctrl+click inside a iframe url, like i have the below iframe tag which shoes google inside the page

```
<iframe id ="dbiframe" src="http://google.com">
</iframe>
```

Now the user should be disable with ctrl+click (new tab) when click any link in google.com

Your helps is much appreciated. thanks in advance

Comment: If you have access to the origin then you can do it with javascript, else its restricted by browser security due to Cross-Origin

Comment: i have the access to the origin...

Comment: Are you able to add some JavaScript in `iframe` document html? Is that application using jQuery or not?